# How to debug jvm_maven_import_external rule in bazel?

Tags: java, maven, bazel

Using bazel 1.0.0 and having some issues with downloading jars from a private maven repository.

Here's the code (updated from maven java example: https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/master/java-maven):

```
repositories = ["https://USER:PASSWORD@nexus-proxy-prd.soma.salesforce.com/nexus/content/groups/public"]
jvm_maven_import_external(name='junit_junit',artifact="junit:junit:4.12",server_urls=repositories)
jvm_maven_import_external(name='com_google_guava_guava',artifact="com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre",server_urls=repositories)
```

USER/PASSWORD are nexus tokens. I'm getting "401" errors and jars can be downloaded with curl using the URL that jvm_maven_import_external tries in the log.

I attempted to remove USER/PASSWORD and putting it into a ~/.netrc file, but get the same "401" error from jvm_maven_import_external. If I attempt the URL in the logs with curl -n, then resource downloads.

My question is how can I debug what the rule is doing so that I can see where the problem lies?

Comment: Hi @Blaine Buxton, I bumped into the same issue. Have you found the solution? HTTP gives the same issue. I tried .netrc and ~/.config/coursier/credentials.properties as well.

Answer (score 0):

This may not have been the issue at the time of your question, but latest github docs point out basic auth for private repos is over HTTP not HTTPS

https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external